# Image of real line under Moebius transformation: center and radius?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

I am having a problem due to what no doubt must be an embarrassing error on my part.

I have a Moebius transformation $\phi(z)=(a z+b)/(c z+d)$ with $a,b,c,d$ complex. As $t$ goes over the reals, $\phi(t)$ moves in a circle. Assume $a$ and $c$  both equal to a complex number $w$ of modulus $\sqrt{x}$ ($x$ real), $b = -(1+x)$ and d = $-(1+w^2)$. According to Ch II, section 41 in Carathéodory's book, the circle has center $$\frac{a \overline{d}- b \overline{c}}{c \overline{d} - d\overline{c}}$$. Here the denominator is $$- w (1 + \overline{w}^2) + \overline{w} (1 + w^2) = - w  - \overline{w} x + \overline{w} + w x = (\overline{w} - w) (1 - x).$$ The numerator equals $$- w (1 + \overline{w}^2) + (1+x)  \overline{w} = \overline{w} - w$$ (since $x = w \overline{w}$). Hence, the center has modulus $1/(1-x)$. However, it is clear that, as w approaches the real number $\sqrt{x}$ (on the circle of radius $\sqrt{x}$ around the origin), it is clear that our circle "tends" towards the circle with center at $1$ and radius $0$. What gives?

Oh,  and the radius is supposed to be $$\frac{|a d - b c|}{|c \overline{d} - \overline{c} d|},$$ which is $$\frac{|-w (1 + w^2) + (1+x) w|}{|(\overline{w}-w) (1-x)|} = \frac{|x w - w^3|}{|(\overline{w}-w) (1-x)|} = \frac{|w^2|}{|1-x|} = \frac{x}{|1-x|},$$ which, again, does not approach $0$ as $w$ approaches $\sqrt{x}$. Again: what gives?

(At least the circle goes through a point at distance $1$ from the origin, reflecting the fact that $
\phi(t)\to 1$ as $t\to \pm \infty$. But this is not the circle we want -- it may be the circle we would have if we let $w\to i \sqrt{x}$.)

Comment: you do get a circle when $ad-bc \neq 0$  and $\frac{c}{d}$ is not real, so that the denominator is never $0$  for real $z.$   You get three explicit complex numbers on the circle, $\frac{b}{d},$   $\frac{a+b}{c+d},$  $\frac{a-b}{c-d},$   these being $z=0,1,-1.$ They are vertices   $v_1, v_2, v_3$ of a triangle, we want the circumscribed circle. For each pair of vertices,  take that line edge and construct its perpendicular bisector, say parametrized  with real $t$  as some $  \frac{v_i + v_j}{2} + t  i ( vj-vi.$ Any two of these perpendiculars must intersect in the center of the circle.$

Comment: A friend points out to me that the calculation above is in fact correct, and that the error is hiding after "it is clear". Even though $f(t)$ depends continuously on $w$ for $t$ fixed, the circles for $w\to \sqrt{x}$ simply do not "tend" to the circle for $w=\sqrt{x}$. (The same segment parametrizes smaller and smaller parts of the circles.) That's an interesting "real-life" example of the pitfalls of reasoning naively with "tends to"!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach to try:

1. Invert the equation $w= \phi(z)$ as $z= \psi(w)$.  Determine the inverse explicitly in terms of $a,b,c,d$.  (You can find the inverse of the matrix associated to the original linear-fractional map.)
2. Then write the real-axis condition $ z -\overline z =0$ as an algebraic equation in the symbols $w$ and $\overline w$. Manipulate that to get the complex-variable  equation of your circle: $(w-c) \overline {(w-c)}= r^2$.